# Value* to Instruction*/LoadInst* casting

Tags: llvm

Can you please tell me if it is possible in LLVM to cast a `Value*` to an `Instruction*/LoadInst*` if for example `isa<LoadInst>(MyValue)` is true? In my particular piece of code:

```
Value* V1 = icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0);
Value* V2 = icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(1);
if (isa<LoadInst>(V1) || isa<LoadInst>(V2)){
...
if(isa<LoadInst>(icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0)))
    LoadInst *LD100 = cast<LoadInst>(icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0));
        Value *C100 = LD100->getPointerOperand(); //HERE COMPILATION ERROR
```

Further, I just need to make `C100->getName()` and I will get the loaded variable.

The compilation error is : `error: ‘LD100’ was not declared in this scope.`

I don't think that I can use cast like that. Can you tell me a method to obtain the loaded variable from a Load instruction correspondent to my ICMP instructions? Or better how I can extract the Load instruction from `icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0)`?

Comment: You are missing the braces around the if-statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the braces around the if-statement. Your code is currently equal to this:

```
if(isa<LoadInst>(icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0))) {
    LoadInst *LD100 = cast<LoadInst>(icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0));
}
Value *C100 = LD100->getPointerOperand(); //HERE COMPILATION ERROR
```

`LD100` is not defined outside the if-statements scope. This would work:

```
if(isa<LoadInst>(icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0))) {
    LoadInst *LD100 = cast<LoadInst>(icmpInstrArray[i]->getOperand(0));
    Value *C100 = LD100->getPointerOperand(); //HERE COMPILATION ERROR
}
```