# How do I try to cast a Value* to a subclass?

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a list of Value* and some of them I know are PHINode*.

I could do `dynamic_cast<PHINode*>(value)` and check if it casted to see if it's a PHINode* but I vaguely recall there's a better way.

Comment: If you're certain that the pointer is a pointer to the subclass, then just do `static_cast<PHINode*>(value)` and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of looking around, these two questions indirectly answered my question

- [How is LLVM isa<> implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038330/how-is-llvm-isa-implemented)
- [Value* to Instruction*/LoadInst* casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560027/value-to-instruction-loadinst-casting)

llvm apparently has a built in type checking system. There's a reference page [here](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates). It works like this

```
if(isa<PHINode>(value)){
    PHINode* phi = cast<PHINode>(value);
}
if(PHINode* phi = dyn_cast<PHINode>(value)){//alternatively
    ...
}
```

And it does appear that you don't need to specify that it's a pointer, so it's not `isa<PHINode*>`

Finally, as it turns out, dynamic_cast will NOT work since they implement their own RTTI

> The LLVM source-base makes extensive use of a custom form of RTTI.
>   These templates have many similarities to the C++ dynamic_cast<>
>   operator, but they don’t have some drawbacks (primarily stemming from
>   the fact that dynamic_cast<> only works on classes that have a
>   v-table).

Comment: Exactly how is this better than the `dynamic_cast` method? Most likely, the `isa` function uses `dynamic_cast` anyway.

Comment: LLVM uses its own typing mechanism that doesn't use the normal c++ vtables. dynamic_cast won't work since these classes aren't c++ polymorphic